# How to use MGTwiiterEngine in iphone view Based Application?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I required to develop a Tweeter Application for iphone. I was trying to use MGTwitterEngine in my iphone app but can’t figure out how to put it together with my iphone View-based Application. If anyone has done it and willing to share info or a demo version implementing MGtwitterEngine in their Iphone app. I would appreciate it. I have got raw MGTwitterEngine Project running on its own but want to integrate it into an IPhone View-based Application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice step by step tutorial for Twitter integration with iPhone application. Have a look at this

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

Comment: I have problem in fetching user timeline and i am already done tweet using your link but i want to fetch timeline so can you help me??